# Remove font's reserved white space to create consistent spacing

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a section which only shows simple text. The text elements differ in size, color, and font-family:

```
<section>
  <div>
    <span>Tester SubHeader</span>
    <h2>Header Test</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet blab bla bla</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

And CSS:

```
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 5rem;
}

div {
  background: cadetblue;
}

h2 {
  /* font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif; */
  /* font-family: 'Merriweather', serif; */
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

I noticed that the H2 element, with its enlarged font size, creates spacing to the left of the element. I read that the font perhaps reserves this white space for letters that are wider than others. Here is an image of the problem:

[image]

You see that there is an ever so slight space to the left of the H2. This happens across different fonts, and during my trial and error on codepen it didn't matter what category the font was in (serif, sans-serif).

The problem is that this creates inconsistent padding/spacing among adjacent elements. Is there a way to eliminate the white space when not needed?

[See working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/6efrxbch/)

Comment: That is only for `H` if you just remove H you can see the next letter `e` or `a` is in sync correctly and also if you remove the font-family from `h2` you will see default font behavior of `h2` where `H` has some tiny little thing at the top.

Comment: The problem occurs with different letters, not just with H. It's not an option to start the sentence with a limited pool of letters...